# Shiny Web App for Browser Audio Recording

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, audio-recording, shinyapps

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a Shiny web application where I need to implement client-side audio recording directly from the user's browser. I've explored a couple of packages and solutions, but I'm **encountering** challenges with both.

Thank you for your assistance!

shinyearr Package: (GitHub: https://github.com/nstrayer/shinyearr)

I attempted to use the shinyearr package, which seems promising for audio recording in a Shiny app. However, I'm facing issues when running my Shiny app on a server, as the package doesn't integrate seamlessly with client-side audio recording. I'd appreciate guidance on how to make this package work in a server-based Shiny environment.

Simple Web Audio Recorder Demo: (GitHub: https://github.com/addpipe/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo)

I also explored the "Simple Web Audio Recorder Demo," but I couldn't figure out how to integrate it effectively into my Shiny app. It appears to be a client-side solution, but I'm unsure of the best approach to connect it to my server-based Shiny application. Any advice or code examples for this integration would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- take the file **style.css** and the folder **js** which are given in the Github repo, and put them in the **www** subfolder of your app;
- include **style.css** in the UI of your app:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(href = "style.css", rel = "stylesheet")
  ),
  # rest of the code here
)
```

- use the package [**html2R**](https://github.com/stla/html2R) (it is on CRAN) to convert the body of the file **index.html** (i.e. the HTML code between `<body>` and  `</body>`) to some R code, and put this R code in your UI (in place of `#rest of the code here`).

And use an empty `server` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the JS code. It works on my local system but not on the server; the record button isn't functioning. Any ideas on fixing this server-side issue?

Comment: @tannazhasanzadeh No idea. Maybe the audio file is saved on the server and you don't get the permission for that.